# ubuntu 18.10 screen flickering (with RX480)

Tags: flicker

I am running Ubuntu 18.10. I think I received a kernel update to 4.18.0-12-generic and the screen keeps on flickering. I have RX480

Comment: Which video driver?

Comment: I think the open source amdgpu driver. I didn't do anything fancy. Just tried booting with kernel 4.18.0-11-generic and the flicker is gone.

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge screen-resolution-extra*` and `sudo reboot`.

Comment: `screen-resolution-extra` is not installed

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: Same problem here, nothing helped. Happens only after recovering from sleep mode.

Comment: Happens to me all the time

Comment: Is there anymore suggestions that we can try?